# Generate RTF file with phpword

Tags: laravel-5, phpword

I have some PHPWord code with Laravel 5 which generates a table with borders. The table displays correctly when created in a Word document, but there are no borders when saving to a .rtf file and the rows are generating infinetly.

The version of Phpword that I use is v0.12.1.